# Why don't migraine headaches and auras consistently have opposite lateralisation?

Tags: lateralization

[A survey by Khalil et al. (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1177/0333102410378050) found that any aura lateralisation can be followed by any headache lateralization, although there was a tendency for headaches to be on the opposite side of the head from their preceding auras which was trending towards significance. On a few occasions I myself have experienced migraines, which always consist of an approximately bilaterally symmetric scintillating scotoma followed by a unilateral headache.

How might cortical spreading depression in **both** hemispheres of the visual cortex result in pain on **only one side** of the head?

<sub>Khalil, N. M., Nicotra, A., & Wilkins, A. J. (2011). [Asymmetry of visual function in migraine with aura: correlation with lateralisation of headache and aura.](https://doi.org/10.1177/0333102410378050) Cephalalgia, 31(2), 213-221.</sub>